# Using loops to replace characters in a string (need help optimizing)

Tags: c++

For one of my CS assignments, I am being told to

"(1) Get a single word of input from the user. Output the word. If the word contains certain characters, use a loop of your choosing to replace them with the corresponding symbols or numbers.

Example output:

```
    Enter word: sixteen
    You entered: sixteen
    New word: $!*t33n
```

You should support these characters:

a -- @

e -- 3

i -- !

g -- 9

s -- $

x -- *

If your word does not contain any of the above characters, just print the original word again."

Now, I was able to figure this out, using a myriad of while and for loops. However, I am under the impression there has to be a more efficient way to complete this task.

Here is the relevant bit of code I am looking to optimize:

```
while (userWord.find('a') != string::npos) {
     hasA = userWord.find('a');

  userWord.replace( userWord.find('a'), 1, "@");

   if (userWord.find('a') != string::npos) {
      hasA = userWord.find('a');

      userWord.replace( userWord.find('a'), 1, "@");
   }
   else if (userWord.find('e') != string::npos) {
      hasA = userWord.find('e');

      userWord.replace( userWord.find('e'), 1, "3");
   }
   else if (userWord.find('i') != string::npos) {
      hasA = userWord.find('i');

      userWord.replace( userWord.find('i'), 1, "!");
   }
   else if (userWord.find('g') != string::npos) {
      hasA = userWord.find('g');

      userWord.replace( userWord.find('g'), 1, "9");
   }
   else if (userWord.find('s') != string::npos) {
      hasA = userWord.find('s');

      userWord.replace( userWord.find('s'), 1, "$");
   }
  else if (userWord.find('x') != string::npos) {
      hasA = userWord.find('x');

      userWord.replace( userWord.find('x'), 1, "*");
   }

}

while (userWord.find('e') != string::npos) {
  hasA = userWord.find('e');

  userWord.replace( userWord.find('e'), 1, "3");

  if (userWord.find('a') != string::npos) {
      hasA = userWord.find('a');

      userWord.replace( userWord.find('a'), 1, "@");
  }
  else if (userWord.find('e') != string::npos) {
      hasA = userWord.find('e');

      userWord.replace( userWord.find('e'), 1, "3");
  }
  else if (userWord.find('i') != string::npos) {
      hasA = userWord.find('i');

      userWord.replace( userWord.find('i'), 1, "!");
  }
  else if (userWord.find('g') != string::npos) {
      hasA = userWord.find('g');

      userWord.replace( userWord.find('g'), 1, "9");
  }
  else if (userWord.find('s') != string::npos) {
      hasA = userWord.find('s');

      userWord.replace( userWord.find('s'), 1, "$");
  }
  else if (userWord.find('x') != string::npos) {
      hasA = userWord.find('x');

      userWord.replace( userWord.find('x'), 1, "*");
  }

}

while (userWord.find('i') != string::npos) {
  hasA = userWord.find('i');

  userWord.replace( userWord.find('i'), 1, "!");

if (userWord.find('a') != string::npos) {
      hasA = userWord.find('a');

      userWord.replace( userWord.find('a'), 1, "@");
  }
  else if (userWord.find('e') != string::npos) {
      hasA = userWord.find('e');

      userWord.replace( userWord.find('e'), 1, "3");
  }
  else if (userWord.find('i') != string::npos) {
      hasA = userWord.find('i');

      userWord.replace( userWord.find('i'), 1, "!");
  }
  else if (userWord.find('g') != string::npos) {
      hasA = userWord.find('g');

      userWord.replace( userWord.find('g'), 1, "9");
  }
  else if (userWord.find('s') != string::npos) {
      hasA = userWord.find('s');

      userWord.replace( userWord.find('s'), 1, "$");
  }
  else if (userWord.find('x') != string::npos) {
      hasA = userWord.find('x');

      userWord.replace( userWord.find('x'), 1, "*");
  }

}

while (userWord.find('g') != string::npos) {
  hasA = userWord.find('g');

  userWord.replace( userWord.find('g'), 1, "9");
  if (userWord.find('a') != string::npos) {
      hasA = userWord.find('a');

      userWord.replace( userWord.find('a'), 1, "@");
  }
  else if (userWord.find('e') != string::npos) {
      hasA = userWord.find('e');

      userWord.replace( userWord.find('e'), 1, "3");
  }
  else if (userWord.find('i') != string::npos) {
      hasA = userWord.find('i');

      userWord.replace( userWord.find('i'), 1, "!");
  }
  else if (userWord.find('g') != string::npos) {
      hasA = userWord.find('g');

      userWord.replace( userWord.find('g'), 1, "9");
  }
  else if (userWord.find('s') != string::npos) {
      hasA = userWord.find('s');

      userWord.replace( userWord.find('s'), 1, "$");
  }
  else if (userWord.find('x') != string::npos) {
      hasA = userWord.find('x');

      userWord.replace( userWord.find('x'), 1, "*");
  }

}

while (userWord.find('s') != string::npos) {
  hasA = userWord.find('s');

  userWord.replace( userWord.find('s'), 1, "$");
 if (userWord.find('a') != string::npos) {
      hasA = userWord.find('a');

      userWord.replace( userWord.find('a'), 1, "@");
  }
  else if (userWord.find('e') != string::npos) {
      hasA = userWord.find('e');

      userWord.replace( userWord.find('e'), 1, "3");
  }
  else if (userWord.find('i') != string::npos) {
      hasA = userWord.find('i');

      userWord.replace( userWord.find('i'), 1, "!");
  }
  else if (userWord.find('g') != string::npos) {
      hasA = userWord.find('g');

      userWord.replace( userWord.find('g'), 1, "9");
  }
  else if (userWord.find('s') != string::npos) {
      hasA = userWord.find('s');

      userWord.replace( userWord.find('s'), 1, "$");
  }
  else if (userWord.find('x') != string::npos) {
      hasA = userWord.find('x');

      userWord.replace( userWord.find('x'), 1, "*");
  }

}

while (userWord.find('x') != string::npos) {
  hasA = userWord.find('x');

  userWord.replace( userWord.find('x'), 1, "*");
  if (userWord.find('a') != string::npos) {
      hasA = userWord.find('a');

      userWord.replace( userWord.find('a'), 1, "@");
  }
  else if (userWord.find('e') != string::npos) {
      hasA = userWord.find('e');

      userWord.replace( userWord.find('e'), 1, "3");
  }
  else if (userWord.find('i') != string::npos) {
      hasA = userWord.find('i');

      userWord.replace( userWord.find('i'), 1, "!");
  }
  else if (userWord.find('g') != string::npos) {
      hasA = userWord.find('g');

      userWord.replace( userWord.find('g'), 1, "9");
  }
  else if (userWord.find('s') != string::npos) {
      hasA = userWord.find('s');

      userWord.replace( userWord.find('s'), 1, "$");
  }
  else if (userWord.find('x') != string::npos) {
      hasA = userWord.find('x');

      userWord.replace( userWord.find('x'), 1, "*");
  }

}
cout << "New word: " << userWord << endl;
```

There has to be a better way than re-nesting each if-statement after each while-loop to ensure each instance of any of the replaceable letters will actually get replaced.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: One good advice is to value the C++ standard libary. The algorithms and functions in there will easily solve the problem in like ten lines.

Comment: If you looped through each character of the string, then everything else could just be in a switch/case statement.

Comment: Since you've already got a working solution and seem to be asking for ways to rewrite it and make it better, maybe http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would be a better fit for this question.

Comment: better to get another program / class having array index and their symbolic value, So when it encounters you can just replace with its value

Comment: Yeah, this is my first time using stackoverflow, my apologies on the wrong section, and Ill be sure to post this question in codereview. With that being said, I will look into converting my onslaught of if-statements into either a switch/case or treating it like an array. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Using C++'s standard template library this should be quite easy. Uses `std::transform` and the `std::map<..>` associative container.

(assuming C++11 is available **See below for a 'true' C++11 implementation!**)

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

// A functor (object posing as function call)
struct charmapper {
    charmapper( const std::map<char, char>& cm):
       charmap( cm )
    {}

    // If the character 'in' is present in the std::map<>
    // return the mapped character, otherwise the original character
    char operator()(char in) const {
        std::map<char, char>::iterator entry = charmap.find(in);
        return (entry == charmap.end()) ? in : entry->second;
    }
    std::map<char, char>  charmap;
};

int main(void) {
   // Here define your character replacements
   std::map<char, char>  toreplace{ {'a', '@'}, {'i', '1'} }; // etc

   std::string  input{ "This is an input string" };
   std::string  output;

   // Now transform the input string, using the charmapper functor
   std::transform(input.begin(), input.end(), std::back_inserter(output),
                  charmapper(toreplace) );

   // Display to check what transform has done
   std::cout << output << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

See & run the program here: https://ideone.com/GROl6p

**EDIT:**
Having given it some more thought, it could be done even better, using more of C++11's features. The basic idea below is that we decorate `std::map` with a function call operator; for the transformation nothing *but* the map should be necessary. This is done by inheriting from `std::map` and defining `operator()`.

In this derived class define C++11's forwarding constructor with variadic template arguments. This means that it is possible to create the derived type with `std::map` 's initializer-list constructor in-situ; no need to create a separate instance of the `std::map` and the derived (decorated) type.

The code is now type safer and what's more, the 'mapper' is now generic and can trivially be used for any replacement mapping operations.

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using std::string; using std::map;

template <typename ...Types>
struct mapper : public map<Types...> {
    typedef map<Types...> Self;
    using map<Types...>::map;

    // C++11 forwarding constructor!
    template <typename ...Args>
    mapper(Args... args) : map<Types...>(args...) {}

    // Decorate the std::map<> with function call operator
    typename Self::mapped_type operator()(const typename Self::key_type& k) const {
        typename Self::const_iterator  ptr = this->find(k);
        return (ptr==this->end()) ? typename Self::mapped_type(k) : ptr->second;
    }
};

int main(void) {
   string  input{ "This is an input string" };
   string  output;

   // Now transform the input string, using the mapperr
   std::transform(input.begin(), input.end(), std::back_inserter(output),
                  mapper<string::value_type, string::value_type>({{'a', '@'}, {'i','1'}}) );

   // Display to check what transform has done
   std::cout << output << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

See it in action here: https://ideone.com/vmON0E

Answer (score 0):

you can do all of that in one loop.

```
int main()
{
  string myWord;
  cout << "enter a word: ";
  cin >> myWord;
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < myWord.size(); i++)
  {
    if(myWord[i]=='a')
      myWord[i] = '@';
    else if(myWord[i] == 'e')
      myWord[i] = '3';
    else if(myWord[i] == 'i')
      myWord[i] = '!';
    else if(myWord[i] == 'g')
      myWord[i] = '9';
    else if(myWord[i] == 's')
      myWord[i] = '$';
    else if(myWord[i] == 'x')
      myWord[i] = '*';
  }
  cout << myWord;
}
```

see it running here http://cpp.sh/86qh

Answer (score 0):

Not going to provide a full code sample because this smells like a homework assignment.

Most efficient way of doing this would be to create a ASCII substitution map:

```
const substitution[] = " !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@BCD3F9H!JKLMNOPQR$TUVW*YZ[\]^_`@bcd3f9h!jklmnopqr$tuvw*yz{|}~";
```

Then just loop through the input and replace each character with the corresponding character in the substitution map:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myWord.size(); i++)
{
    myWord[i] = substitution[myWord[i] - 32];
}
```

Comment: I would just start out by initializing the substitution map to an equality substitution, then changing the ones I needed to remap.

Comment: That's what haavee did in his solution. :-)  There are plenty of ways to do this.