# why can't i replace char on a string like this?

Tags: c++, regex, dictionary, vector, replace

I'm trying to replace characters from the following map:  `const map<char, vector<char>> ass`, note I have this string `pas`and I want to replace all (map value) vector chars to the Corresponding map key, I tried to iterate the map with a for cycle like this: (I got this code from another question on stackoverflow)

```
for (auto const &ent1 : ass) {

    //ent1.first = first key
    //ent1.second = second key
}
```

So I tried to iterate the map value vector like this:

```
string char1;
string char2;
string wr;

for (auto const &ent1 : ass) {

    for (int i = 0; i < ent1.second.size(); i++) {

        specialValues += ent1.second[i];

        char2 = ent1.second[i];
        char1 = ent1.first;

        regex e("([" + char1 + "])");

        cout << ("([" + char1 + "])");
        cout << char2;

        wr = regex_replace("c1a0", e, char2);
    }

}
```

So I want the string "c1a0" to become "ciao" after the loops, but it just doesn't change anything,

I also tried:

```
wr = regex_replace("c1a0", e, "o");
```

> output : c1a0

```
regex e("([0])");
wr = regex_replace("c1a0", e, char2);
```

> output : c1a2

I don't know, it makes no sense for me. I don't understand, can you help me figure out what's wrong in my code?

Of course if I write:

```
regex e("([0])");
wr = regex_replace("c1a0", e, "o");
```

It gives me "c1ao" that's what I want.

Comment: I think [the "Using loops to replace characters in a string" thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33270917/3832970) can be of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code works for me:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    const map<char, vector<char>> ass = {
        { '1', {'i'} },
        { '0', {'o'} },
    };

    string char1;
    string char2;
    string wr = "c1a0";

    for (auto const &ent1 : ass) {

        for (int i = 0; i < ent1.second.size(); i++) {

            //specialValues += ent1.second[i];

            char2 = ent1.second[i];
            char1 = ent1.first;

            regex e("([" + char1 + "])");

            cout << ("([" + char1 + "])") << std::endl;
            cout << char2<< std::endl;

            wr = regex_replace(wr, e, char2);
            cout << wr << std::endl;

        }

    }
}
```

But IMHO, regex here is overkill. You can iterate over string manually and replace character like in the following snippet:

```
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct replace_entry {
    char with;
    std::set<char> what;
};

int main() {
    const std::vector<replace_entry> replaceTable = {
        { 'i', {'1'} },
        { 'o', {'0'} },

    };

    string input = "c1a0";

    for (auto const &replaceItem : replaceTable) {
        for (char& c: input ) {
            if(replaceItem.what.end() != replaceItem.what.find(c)) {
                c = replaceItem.with;
            }
        }

    }
    cout << input << std::endl;
}
```

Yet another approach is to create 256 elements array of chars

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class ReplaceTable {
private:
    char replaceTable_[256];

public:
    constexpr ReplaceTable() noexcept 
        : replaceTable_()
    {
        replaceTable_['0'] = 'o';
        replaceTable_['1'] = 'i';
    }

    constexpr char operator[](char what) const noexcept {
        return replaceTable_[what];
    }

};

// One time initialization
ReplaceTable g_ReplaceTable;

int main() {

    std::string input = "c1a0";

    // Main loop
    for (char& c: input ) {
        if(0 != g_ReplaceTable[c] ) c = g_ReplaceTable[c];
    }

    std::cout << input << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: ok i just stupidly confused char1 with char2, thanks for your multiple solutions answer btw